# EXCEL - using SMALL to calculate start dates - ignoring blank cells

Tags: excel

i am desperately trying to create a formula to work out when to run training courses based on start dates, the course will depend on the role, so Col A = a number of roles, B = person, C = start date.  (I know the answer is to do this in Access, but I have to deal with what I have been given)  an example of the data is below.  The output I want is knowing when the first 2 people will be available to train, then the next 2....

```
Role  Name   Date
IT    Bob    02/02/15
BA    Dave   03/06/15
GS    Phil   06/06/15
IT    
IT    Kate   03/03/15
```

The formula I have used is =SMALL(IF(A:A="IT",C:C),2) - this seems to return the on board date of the first 2 as 02/02/15 as its counting the blanks, it should give me 03/03/15.  Please help.

Jen

Answer (score 0):

Could add a second IF condition:

```
=SMALL(IF(A1:A10="IT",IF(C1:C10<>"",C1:C10)),2)
```

Comment: Though perhaps NOT referencing entire columns!

Comment: I agree, referencing entire columns is generally bad news for array formulas, though user was using it in her workbook so I'm guessing she's on MS Office 2010 or higher which is equipped to "optimize" whole column references so that the formula doesn't actually calculate the whole column.  That being said, best practice is definitely to use defined ranges instead of whole columns, so I will edit my answer to reflect that

Comment: Can you clarify? I didn't realise that was the case with array formulas? In fact, I was led to believe the opposite. For example, if I enter data into just the first ten or so rows in columns A and B of an otherwise empty worksheet, and enter the array formula =SUM((A:A="A")*(B:B="B")) into just 10 cells somewhere, e.g. D10:D10, there is definitely a noticeable impact. Just try entering a further value somewhere in column A or B and watch the navigation post-ENTER crawl.

Comment: I could have sworn that I read that Excel 2010 and Excel 2013 were optimized to only calculate to the last populated cell in a column if a whole column reference was provided, but I can't find anything that says that, and in fact am only finding evidence that shows nothing of the sort ever happened.  Must be something I simply wish existed and have mistaken that wish for fact, my apologies.

Comment: To be honest I wasn't 100% sure, though the few tests I'd done strongly suggested that it wasn't the case. Perhaps you're confusing this with the change which simply meant that, in those newer versions, it became permissible to reference entire columns (I've a feeling it wasn't even valid syntax in e.g. 2003), though of guess being valid doesn't isn't the same as being quick!

Comment: Hi - This is producing a #NUM error. - Perhaps should have included the fact that "IT" will be avariable, so if I am changing a course, I will change that to say "BA" or "GS" each of which have different class sizes.  I can get it to work but not to exclude the blanks.

Comment: Stupid me - worked out why - basically because still dont have enough people to meet the minimum class size.